# How to export shapefile to SpatiaLite

Tags: qgis, spatial-database, spatialite

I have a shapefile with one layer. I can open it with QGIS. Now I want to convert this shapefile or layer to Spatialite database.

How can I do it? Is it possible to do with QGIS?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is a GUI application called [spatialite-gui](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index) that allows you to import shapefiles and build spatial indexes.

Answer (score 19):

Several options!

1. Within QGIS, you can "File|Save as" the shapefile directly as a
   spatialite database; the limitation here is that you can make a
   database with only one shapefile.
2. You can use the command line `spatialite_tool` to load and manage shapefiles (tutorial [here](http://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-cookbook/html/impexp.html)).
3. It is really worth exploring the [spatialite-gui](https://www.gaia-gis.it/fossil/spatialite_gui/index)
   and spatialite-gis standalone applications, which let you view and
   modify data directly. In the gui app, create a new database (second
   toolbar button), then load a shapefile (green world icon with arrow) - you must know and input the SRID of the shapefile in the resulting dialog. The advantage here is that you can easily add multiple shapefiles, and build a large database.

Answer (score 12):

Yes it can be done with QGis.
Using the QSpatiaLite Plugin

"Manage your SpatiaLite databases within QGis"  [image]

After installing the plugin you can run it.
[image]
You will receive a series of messages/errors stating that you do not have a spatialite db.
it will step you through getting one installed (choose a location for the file) and finally converting it to spatial.
Then in this dialog you can import your QGis layer.
[image]
Then: you don't really need this. It only works to create a new db.
From the QGIS menu
Layer | Save As...

From the QGIS 'Save vector layer as...' dialog box
Choose Spatialite from the Format drop down list.

Answer (score 10):

You can right-click the layer and select "save layer as..." and choose spatiaLite as your format.  Your only option there is to create a new database, i.e. you cannot add it to an existing database.

The QspatiaLite plugin adds a lot of functionality to QGIS, so give that a try as well.